# how to bypass google sign-in page in app engine to access certain html file in java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, backend, google-search-console

How to bypass google sign-in page in GWT with GAE to access certain html file in Java backend servlet? I tried to put the security-constraint in web.xml like following :

```
 <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>verifysite</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/test.html</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>*</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
```

But it still doesn't work. It always redirect me into the google sign-in page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Role-name * means that you want your users to be logged in to access the resource :

> If the authorization constraint specifies a user role of *, then any users signed in with a Google Account can access the URL

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml?hl=FR#Security_and_Authentication

If you want test.html to be available to anyone, its URI must not be in the scope of any `<security-constraint>`.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for your answer I'll try to remove it. But I think I still need to start my backend servlet using /_ah/start that needs to have admin security-constraint in it. So my purpose is I want to verify my backend site on appengine using this html file. The backend site looks like https://backendname-dot-appname.appspot.com/verify.html. How can I do this without get redirected to the google sign-in page? thanks.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong : you want to test a secured feature from an unsecured page ?

Comment: Hi Michael, you we're right. It turns out that on my web.xml I forgot that there is <security-constraint> that has url-pattern to be /* with role of *. And the other things that I also forgot to change is my backends to be public (it's default to private). thank you very much.